# Laravel Passing Validation Errors to View

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing, laravel-validation

I have the following Laravel 4.2 controller code in a store method:

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
   return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
}
```

I've tested this code with var_dump and the $validator is definitely returning the correct error messages.

The errors however are not being passed to the view. When attempting `var_dump($errors)` on the view I get the following exception 
`Undefined variable: errors`.

I've also tried (by accident) `var_dump($error)`and it is of type `object(Illuminate\Support\ViewErrorBag)` however it does not contain any errors.

Does anyone know what the problem might be? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show the code you have. `$errors` is shared view variable and it's always defined, unless you mess with the `ViewServiceProvider`.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk Yes, you are 100% right, we don't need to check $errors variable. Sorry about that comment. John this should give error `var_dump($error)` but I believe this is a typo. Happy New year guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking into this issue for two whole days - I've finally fixed it! In the end I removed the vendor folder and ran `composer update`. I can only assume that something within Laravel was corrupt in the initial download.